# jQuery version conflict in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I have noticed that I am loading 2 different versions of jquery in my wordpress site.

I  see that i referenced version 1.8 in my header (via the google code), but cannot seem to find the 1.6.4 version in order to remove it?

My fancy-box plugin is no longer working, and I'm not sure what I did to cause this?
When i click on an image it brings up the fancy-box loading image, but then the overlay just covers the page and does not open the image.

Any advice to remove this version conflict would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Why did you ask the same question elsewhere? It's always better to edit the existing question and be more specific rather than open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page inspector in Chrome I can see the script is just loaded in the header.

It's probably some plugin that's loading this version.
What you could do is disable your plugins one by one to see which one resolves it.

Comment: Thank you.  I saw this in the console when I try a and open a 'fancybox image'      "Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutBack'"

Comment: This could be indeed a result of two colliding jQuery versions. I'd first try to eliminate the duplicated versions and then see if that resolves it.

Comment: -i have tried to disable all plugins. and the old jquery version still appears in the inspect element?